# Magento 2 table weight name

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to do a major changes in the weights of my products in Magento 2.

I don't want to manually change all the products, that will take days. I want to change them in the database directly, but in which `table(s)` are the `product weights` stored?

Comment: However you can make script for it.. load all products and update their weights.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: i just add example you can go with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');


$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$_product = $_product->setWeight(4.0000);

$_product->save();
```

It is a just example for you.

To achieve your requirement you have to `getProductCollection` make `foreach` loop over that collection and get product from that collection than you can apply this example as per your requirement.

This example will not work in .phtml file or your extension.

To check this file you need to create external .php file on root of your magento 2.

Hope this will helps you.